# Is $realtobits synthsizeiable?

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, vivado

I have been trying to figure out why my verilog program is not working for hours.  To test it I just added some constants as inputs to my module and I am using the integrated logic analyser to check the outputs.  For some reason all of my intermediate values are 0.0 (64 bit float).  I then used the ILA to check the u and d inputs and their values are zero.  Right now I am using $realtobits to create constants out of float values.  Is this synthsizeiable?

```
binomial_controller bc(.u($realtobits(1.0025031276057951857)),
                       .d($realtobits(0.99750312239745997367)),
                       .u_v($realtobits(1.0026284483291278971)),
                       .d_v($realtobits(0.99737844229982886013)),
                       .p_up($realtobits(0.49968750024413099986)),
                       .p_up_v($realtobits(99.500999000666340066)),
                       .p_dn($realtobits(0.50031249975586900014)),
                       .p_dn_v($realtobits(0.50035863068484875971)),
                       .int_exp($realtobits(0.99999843750122074937)),
                       .price($realtobits(100.0)),
                       .strike($realtobits(100.0)),
                       .start(start),
                       .clk(cclk),
                       .last_nine_tree_elements(r),
                       .ready(ready));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer. No, I don't think it is.

There is a very useful online reference/help document which has pages describing Verilog constructs and syntax. It has a page on the [`$realtobits`](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00006.htm) function, which state

> Conversion functions are not synthesizable.

I can't vouch for the accuracy of the source, but it makes sense. The Verilog `$...` functions tend to be helper functions for things like memory initialisation, displaying in simulation, etc. as opposed to actually synthesisable constructs. This isn't always the case - things like `$signed` are synthesizable as far as I know.

Furthermore, the complex data types, like `real`, `time`, and `event` are also not synthesizable. From that standpoint it therefore makes sense that anything involving converting to and from them cannot be synthesized.

---

As @PeterGreen points out in the comments, whether a construct is synthesizable comes down as much as anything to the synthesis tool. As you specify Xilinx as a tag, you can refer to the [XST User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/books/docs/xst/xst.pdf).

Table 7-33 on page 518 of that document - in a section titled "Verilog System Tasks and Functions Supported in XST" - it is clearly stated which system functions are supported and which are ignored.

`$realtobits` is not listed specifically in that table, so it falls under the final entry which says: `All others: Ignored`, indicating that it is not supported by the tool.

Comment: Makes sense I just figured it would be one of those cases where since it was a constant it would synthsize.

Comment: I don't think there is an official "synthisable subset" anymore and evern when there was tool vendors often ignored parts of it. So really the only answer is to check your tool vendors documentation.

Comment: Unofficial Guide: http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-SNUG-SV_Synthesizable-SystemVerilog_paper.pdf